# setting and referencing state from multiple useEffect

Tags: reactjs

My first proper react build so shoot me down wherever you see fit.

`tl;dr I'm trying to set state in one place and immediately reference it elsewhere before it has registered.`

I am using the [Google Maps React Wrapper](https://github.com/googlemaps/react-wrapper/tree/main) and Redux.
I'm loading a list of route data from an external source that I convert to [`PolyLine`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Polyline) instances and display on the map. I store the PolyLines in a list with `const [linesList, setLinesList] = useState(aList)`

I also have input controls that allow you to filter which routes are displayed, adjust the style etc.

For instance I have a `useEffect` set up with a Date input value as a dependency. If you change the selected date it loops over `linesList` and hides some from the map based on a date comparison.
I also have another `useEffect` set up with a checkbox as its dependency that hides/shows a HeatmapLayer based on the currently visible lines on the map.

**My Problem**.
If I change my date filter, I loop over `linesList` in state and update the `visible` property of each item accordingly. As I understand it I then have to call `setLinesList` again with the updated list.

If I toggle my heatmap on I also have to go through all my lines, constructing the heatmap data from any that are visible.

So, if my heatmap is on when I apply my date filter, I trigger the first `useState`, loop over the lines in `linesList` setting their visibility, call `setLinesList` to update state ***then*** I need to immediately trigger my heatmap method which also tries to loop over `linesList`  but finds it not yet updated from the previous filtering step.

Wow, I dunno if that makes any sense. Sorry.
I assume I'm missing some fundamental concept regarding use of `useState` or best practice for structuring components.

Any thoughts?